# Error after pulling Nuxt project made using an older version of Nuxt

Tags: npm, nuxt.js

What does error mean?

Note that on the other computer, I did upgrade Nuxt and everything works well.

After pulling to my other computer, I get this error when trying to run npm install.

[image]

Here is my package.json file

[image]

And yes, there is no node_modules right now, which deleted thinking its a Nuxt upgrade issue.

Comment: You don't have a `package-lock.json` for some reason. This file needs to be committed to git. If you don't, you'll need to figure out yourself which versions are compatible between each other by yourself. As told in the error, you can also try `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` or get the matching versions manually. The reason is because some packages need a specific version to work and when you have `^` in the version of a package, it only gives a range.

Comment: Mainly bump the version of the firebase nuxt module. Looking at their Github release page may help regarding the changelog to figure out which version it's using internally.